Firebase Emulator Suite throws: Permission denied because no Storage ruleset is currently loaded, check your rules for syntax errors
I'm integrating the Resize Images by Firebase extension. I'm trying to create a new bucket, so I attach it to this extension.
firebase.json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "storage": [
    {
      "target": "default",
      "rules": "storage.default.rules"
    },
    {
      "target": "mc-hogar-articulos",
      "rules": "storage.articulos.rules"
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "extensions": {
    "storage-resize-articulos": "firebase/storage-resize-images@0.2.5"
  }
}

.firebaserc
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "cloudfunctions-express-templat"
  },
  "targets": {
    "cloudfunctions-express-templat": {
      "storage": {
        "mc-hogar-articulos": [
          "mc-hogar-articulos.appspot.com"
        ],
        "default": [
          "cloudfunctions-express-templat.appsport.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "etags": {},
  "dataconnectEmulatorConfig": {}
}

storage.default.rules
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

storage.articulos.rules
rules_version = '2';

service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

I run firebase emulators:start and everything is fine until I enter the Emulator UI at Storage menu item and I get the error " Permission denied because no Storage ruleset is currently loaded, check your rules for syntax errors."
How could I resolve this?
